# Equivalent code for VB .net 2005

Tags: .net, vb.net, equivalent

I have the following code sample in VB .net 2008

```
Public Function CheckPathFunction(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    Return System.IO.File.Exists(path)
End Function

Public Function PathExists(ByVal path As String, ByVal timeout As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim exists As Boolean = True
    Dim t As New Thread(DirectCast(Function() CheckPathFunction(path), ThreadStart))

    t.Start()

    Dim completed As Boolean = t.Join(timeout)
    If Not completed Then
        exists = False
        t.Abort()
    End If

    Return exists
End Function
```

Unfortunately I have to work with Vb .net 2005 and net framework 2.0; How can I accomplish the same for VB .net 2005?, VB .net 2005 does not support the syntax corresponding to the code line num. 3:

```
Function() CheckPathFunction(path)
```

Please note that the function to call requires a parameter and returns a value

---

I've tried using a delegate as indicated next but does not work

```
Private Delegate Function CheckPath(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

Public Function CheckPathFunction(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    Return IO.File.Exists(path)
End Function

Public Function PathExists(ByVal path As String, ByVal timeout As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim checkPathDelegate As New CheckPath(AddressOf CheckPathFunction)

    Dim exists As Boolean = True
    Dim t As New Thread(checkPathDelegate(path))

    t.Start()

    Dim completed As Boolean = t.Join(timeout)
    If Not completed Then
        exists = False
        t.Abort()
    End If

    Return exists
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: Where in the original code does it get the return value from the `CheckPathFunction` method?  It appears that it returns true as long as the method completes within the specified timeout, but it doesn't actually see if the method found the file or not.

Comment: @SteveDog, if detects that the file exist or not while the timeout is not reached returns the corresponding value, if it can't determine if the file exist when the timeout is reached returns false, this function is intended to check for file exist in a network share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking as base structure the code by @eol the final working code is:

```
 Class KeyValuePair
      Public Path As String
      Public Found As Boolean
 End Class

 Public Sub CheckPathFunction(ByVal dataObject As Object)
      dataObject.Found = IO.Directory.Exists(dataObject.Path)
 End Sub

 Public Function PathExists(ByVal path As String, ByVal timeout As Integer) As Boolean
      Dim exists As Boolean

      Dim data As New KeyValuePair
      data.Path = path

      Dim t As New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf CheckPathFunction))
      t.Start(data)

      Dim completed As Boolean = t.Join(timeout)
      If Not completed Then
           exists = False
           t.Abort()
      Else
           exists = data.Found
      End If

      Return exists
 End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1h2f2459%28v=vs.80%29) on calling Thread constructor using ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate.  Since you're in VB you ought to be able to just do this:

```
Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf CheckPathFunction)

t.Start(path)
```

Well, that's the answer for firing up the thread.  But I agree with SteveDog, that it's not actually returning whether the file exists or not, only if the thread completed or timed out.

EDIT to Return Value:
One way to get that value back would be to pass in an object, not just the path.  Then use the object to pass back the result.

So declare a class, like:

```
Class DataHolder
    Public Path As String
    Public Found As Boolean
End Class
```

Change CheckPathFunction like:

```
Public Sub CheckPathFunction(ByVal rawData As Object)
    Dim data As DataHolder = DirectCast(rawData, DataHolder)
    data.Found = System.IO.File.Exists(data.Path)
End Sub
```

And change PathExists like:

```
Public Function PathExists(ByVal path As String, ByVal timeout As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim exists As Boolean
    Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf CheckPathFunction) '  (DirectCast(Function() CheckPathFunction(path), ThreadStart))
    Dim data As DataHolder = New DataHolder
    data.Path = path
    t.Start(data)

    Dim completed As Boolean = t.Join(timeout)
    If Not completed Then
        exists = False
        t.Abort()
    Else
        exists = data.Found
    End If

    Return exists
End Function
```

Comment: if detects the file exist or not before the timeout occurs it returns the proper value True or False, else if the exist checking is taking more time than the timeout, then also returns False

Comment: Try running some tests where it shouldn't find the file.  I tested it as-is and they came back true when they should have been false.  The call to Join doesn't return the return value of CheckPathFunction, it only returns whether the Thread completed or the timeout was reached.

Comment: Does your sample really works for you in VB .net 2005?, I'm getting an Incorrect argument Error message in the code line that creates the new Thread "dim t as new Thread(AddressOf ChecPAthFunction)"

Comment: It works for .NET Framework 2.0.  What exactly is the error?  Perhaps it's b/c I have Strict Off.  Try changing the type of CheckPathFunction to (ByVal data as Object) and directcasting data into DataHolder.